# Как возвратить переменную float из функции без округления в arduino IDE?

Tags: c++, функции, arduino, float

Я составил программу для ардуино для передачи показаний с термометра в последовательный порт:

```
//не все переменные пока задействованы в коде
#define SD_CS 2
#include <math.h>
#define TERMIST_B 4300.0
#define VIN 5.0
#define TERM A0
int sd;
float temp;
char command;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(TERM, INPUT);
//программа ждёт открытия порта
while(!Serial.available()) {}
//отправляет сообщение о подключении компу
Serial.println("ping");
}


void loop() {
//программа ждёт пока комп не передаст 'S' для снятия показаний с термометра.
while(command != 'S') {
  command = Serial.read();
}
command = ' ';
//вызывает функцию
temp = Termo_Indicat();
//отправляет показания
Serial.println(temp);
}

int Termo_Indicat() {
//вычисление температуры по показаниям с датчика
float voltage = analogRead(TERM) * VIN / 1024.0;
float r1 = voltage / (VIN - voltage);
float temperature = 1./( 1./(TERMIST_B)*log(r1)+1./(25. + 273.) ) - 273;
//возвращает значение
return temperature;
}
```

Я столкнулся с проблемой: return возвращает округлённое значение.
Например:
*temperature = 17.49*, но *return* возвращает *17.00*.
Если перенести вычисления из функции в основной код, то проблема исчезает
=> проблема в return.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться))

Comment: Это не округление, а усечение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int Termo_Indicat()` замените на  `float Termo_Indicat()`

и все заработает.